# My function rerurns a wrong value c++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>


using namespace std;

int StrInt(int x,string y)
{

    return y.at(x);
    cout << y.at(x) << "hallo";
}
int Get_Int(int linie, int zeichen){
    ifstream file;
        string line;
        vector<string>lines;
        file.open("C:/Soi/input/input.txt");
        if(file.is_open())
        {
            cout << "file is open" << endl;
            int x = 0;
            lines.resize(1);
            while(getline(file, line))
            {
                lines[x] = line;
                lines.push_back(line);
                x++;
                cout << lines[x] ;

            }
            lines.erase (lines.begin()+x);
            cout << endl;

        }
        else{
            cerr<<"file could not be opened!";

        }
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++)
        {
                cout << lines[i] << "   /" << i << endl;
        }
        string hh = lines[linie];
        cout << hh.at(zeichen) << " hallo" << endl;
        cout << "returned value: " << hh.at(zeichen) << endl;
        return hh.at(zeichen);

}


int main() {
    cout << "Programm gestartet" << endl;
    int zeichen = 0;
    int linie = 0;
    int resultat = Get_Int(linie, zeichen);
    int opperand1 = 2;
    int opperand2 = 48;


    if (opperand1 + opperand2 == resultat){
        cout << resultat << endl << "true" ;
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        cout << resultat << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The normal value that im trying to get would be: 3
the code isnt finished yet.
later on im trying to print out, if the two values are like the result.
I tryed making some changes in the code, but it didnt work.
the value, that im getting from

cout <<  hh.at(zeichen)

is different from the value, that im getting from

cout << resultat

Thank you very much

sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 2):

Your function is declared to return an `int`, but what you return is:

```
    string hh = lines[linie];
    /*...*/
    return hh.at(zeichen);
```

The problem is that `string::at` returns a `char&` and `char`s happily convert to `int` without problems, but you wont get the result you expect. You have to parse the number, ie something like:

```
    return hh.at(zeichen) - '0';
```

Answer (score 1):

`hh.at(zeichen)` is the character at position `zeichen` from string `hh`. The type is `char &`.

When you print that character with `cout << hh.at(zeichen)` it prints the character, for example '0'.

```
int Get_Int(int linie, int zeichen) {
    ...
    return hh.at(zeichen);
}

int result = Get_Int(linie, zeichen);
```

In this function you return the character, but the compiler needs to convert it to an `int`. What is now important is how `char` is stored and what values it has. `char` just contains numbers of (normally) one byte length. How these are interpreted depends on the system. For current PCs characters are normally stored as ASCII. A '0' has the ASCII code 48.

When you print a `char`, then you get the character printed with the same ASCII code (code 48, char '0'). If you print an `int` like `result` you get the number printed (first converted to a string, then printed; number 48, string "48").

You can either print `(char)result` which will convert the `int` back to a `char` which `cout` will print as a character. Or you can convert the `char` to the number represented by the character in the char. In case of ASCII encoding and if you are sure that all characters are representing numbers you can subtract `hh.at(zeichen) - '0'` which gives you 0 for '0', 1 for '1' and so on. But you should keep in mind that this only works for character represenations like ASCII and EBCDIC where '0' up to '9' are represented by character codes that are all neighbours and in the same order as the numbers.